# django rest framework api documentation through swagger

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, swagger

It is already giving the swagger inbuilt page on localhost. It is reading my urls perfectly. But i am unable to define the interior headers, response body. I dont know where to define it and how to connect it with my django project.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from users import views
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='Pastebin API')


urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^api/v1/users/emailsignup/', views.SignUp.as_view()),
url(r'^api/v1/users/userget/', views.UserDetail.as_view()),
url(r'^$', schema_view),
]
```

Thus the schema_view is given . But plz expalain me how to define my response body in it with code.

Comment: any details about this or

Comment: can anyone tell me about raml approach in django